# How to return a List<File>, stored in a DocumentSet, based on the Current ListItem?

Tags: 2013, caml-query, document-set

I have 2 ListItems, each has a DocumentSet with 2 documents each. I'm attempting to download only those Documents attached to the current ListItem.

This is my first time working with documentSets.

This is What I've tried

```
     CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery
    {
        //<-- Returns only a Single file which is wrong
        ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>" +
                                            "<Query>" +
                                            "<Where>" +
                                            "<Eq>" +
                                            "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                                            "<Value Type='Int'>" + Item["ID"] + "</Value>" +
                                            "</Eq>" +
                                            "</Where>" +
                                            "</Query>" +
                                            "</View>"

        // <--- Returns all 4 files which is wrong
        //ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
        //         <Query>
        //            <Where>
        //                <Eq>
        //                   <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
        //                   <Value Type='int'>0</Value>
        //                 </Eq>
        //             </Where>
        //          </Query>
        //       </View>"
    };
    Web web = ctx.Web;
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(SharePointConnector.DocumentLibrary);
    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
    ctx.Load(items, collection => collection.Include(i => i.File.ServerRelativeUrl, i => i.File.Name));

    try
    {
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("SharePoint Communication error - Message: {0}\n", ex.Message));
        SharePointConnector.lstExceptions.Add(Utilities.Exception(Service.Type.Sharepoint, ex, null));
        Utilities.ShowEXITMessage();
    }

    return items.Select(i => i.File).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is waht I ended up going with

```
Web web = ctx.Web;
        ListCollection lists = web.Lists;
        var docLib = web.Lists.GetByTitle(SharePointConnector.DocumentLibrary);
        ctx.Load(docLib,
                           d => d.Title,
                           d => d.RootFolder.Name,
                           d => d.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl );

        ctx.Load(docLib);

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        ctx.Load(docLib);
        ctx.Load(docLib.RootFolder);
        ctx.Load(docLib.RootFolder.Folders);
        ctx.Load(docLib.RootFolder.Files);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        FolderCollection fcol = docLib.RootFolder.Folders;

        string s = docLib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;

        List<Document.WithMetaData> filez = new List<Document.WithMetaData>();
        foreach (Folder f in fcol)
        {
            //Find Parent Folder of the Current ITEM
            if ((f.Name).ToLower() == (Item["FileLeafRef"]).ToString().ToLower())
            {
                ctx.Load(f.Files, 
                    items => items.Include(
                                            item => item.ListItemAllFields));
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                FileCollection fileCol = f.Files;
                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in fileCol)
                {
                    //Access your file here

                });
                }
            }
        }
```